# Any intuitive answer to the summation of power of 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+\dots+2^n = 2^{(n+1)} - 1$$

I want to know is there a simple (visual/intuitive/elementary)  explanation for this. How can I explain the reason behind this result to a layman?

Comment: Would something along the lines of starting with $2^{n+1}$ objects and repeated taking away half of the remainder work?

Comment: $2\times S=S+2^{n+1}-1$, by inspection.